# Snake java game

Tags: java

Seeing some tutorial about snake game,I want to make the "walls" disappear so the snake can go to the end and he will appear on the other side.

Here the relevant code:

```
 public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    static final int SCREEN_WIDTH = 600;
    static final int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600;
    static final int UNIT_SIZE = 25;
    static final int GAME_UNITS = (SCREEN_WIDTH*SCREEN_HEIGHT)/UNIT_SIZE;
    static final int DELAY = 75;
    final int x[] = new int[GAME_UNITS];
    final int y[] = new int[GAME_UNITS];
    int bodyParts = 6;
    boolean running = false;


public void checkCollisions(){
    for (int i = bodyParts; i>0 ; i--){
        if (x[0] == x[i] && y[0] == y[i]){
            running = false;
        }
    }

    if (x[0] <= 0){
        x[0] = SCREEN_WIDTH;
//            running = false;
    }
    if (x[0] >= SCREEN_WIDTH){
        x[0] = 0;
//            running = false;
        }

    if (y[0] <= 0 ){
        y[0] = SCREEN_HEIGHT;
//            running = false;
    }

    if (y[0] >= SCREEN_HEIGHT){
        y[0] = 0;
//          running = false;
    }

    if (!running){
        timer.stop();
    }

}
```

for :

```
    if (x[0] >= SCREEN_WIDTH){
        x[0] = 0;
//            running = false;
        }
```

and for:

```
        if (y[0] >= SCREEN_HEIGHT){
        y[0] = 0;
//          running = false;
    }
```

everyting working fine.
 but when:

```
       if (x[0] <= 0){
        x[0] = SCREEN_WIDTH;
//            running = false;
    }
```

and when:

```
       if (y[0] <= 0 ){
        y[0] = SCREEN_HEIGHT;
//            running = false;
    }
```

the snake just get stuck at x=0 or y=0 and doesn't move to the other side of the screen.

Comment: Please read: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: I can imagine numerous problems you'll encounter while making this change to the game "rules", but for a start you should probably make your if-checks exclusive. At the moment you're checking for `x[0] <= 0` and also `x[0] >= 0` and *both* of those match when `x[0]` is zero. So I suggest replacing `<=` with `<` so that only one check matches in that situation. (Same for your checks on `y[0]`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can jump to the other side by taking the mod of the position. If your playing field is size 10 and the snake is at hypothetical position `x = -1`, the modulo will give you `x = -1 % 10`, so 9.